# How to pass variable to Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker custom class

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to pass a two-way data binded variable to Angular-UI-Bootstrap Datepicker customClass. But the data binding doesn't work inside my customClass function, it just gives me the value I initialized *chosenUser* variable with.

Example:

> 1. I load the site and *getDayClass* gets called with data initialized in *chosenUser* (undefined in this case)
> 2. I choose an user from the site and the two-way data bind works correctly everywhere else but in *getDayClass* function
> 3. So in *getDayClass* *chosenUser* is still displayed as undefined, even though it isn't

So any changes made to variables after the first load of *getDayClass* don't get passed inside that function. I just can't understand why it doesn't work in there.

Here is a stripped version of my angular controller code:

```
function CalendarController() {
   var vm = this;

   //THIS IS THE VARIABLE (USER OBJECT) I'M TRYING TO PASS TO getDayClass
   vm.chosenUser = {};

   //OPTIONS PASSED TO BOOTSTRAP DATEPICKER
   vm.options = {
        customClass: getDayClass
   };

   //THIS IS THE FUNCTION I RUN FROM HTML WITH NG-CLICK AND IT EXECUTES 
   //FUNCTION getDayClass (AMONG OTHER THINGS)
   vm.refresh = function() {
      $("#calendar").data("$uibDatepickerController").refreshView();
   }

   function getDayClass(data) {
       var date = data.date,
       mode = data.mode;

      //RETURNS UNDEFINED (ONLY INSIDE THIS FUNCTION) 
      //EVEN AFTER USER HAS BEEN CHOSEN
      console.log(vm.chosenUser);
       ...
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to store 'chosenUser' into an array instead of using plain javascript object notation. Something like:

```
function CalendarController() {
       var vm = this;

       //THIS IS THE VARIABLE I'M TRYING TO PASS TO getDayClass
       vm.chosenUser = ["UserNameWillBeHere"];

       //OPTIONS PASSED TO BOOTSTRAP DATEPICKER
       vm.options = {
            customClass: getDayClass
       };

       //THIS IS THE FUNCTION I RUN FROM HTML WITH NG-CLICK AND IT EXECUTES 
       //FUNCTION getDayClass (AMONG OTHER THINGS)
       vm.refresh = function() {
          $("#calendar").data("$uibDatepickerController").refreshView();
       }

       function getDayClass(data) {
           var date = data.date,
           mode = data.mode;

          //RETURNS UNDEFINED (ONLY INSIDE THIS FUNCTION) 
          //EVEN AFTER USER HAS BEEN CHOSEN
          console.log(vm.chosenUser[0]);
           ...
       };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work :/ The problem is that any changes done to chosenUser after getDayClass is first loaded don't appear in getDayClass. And getDayClass is loaded when the site is first loaded so the two-way data bind of chosenUser is of no use because for some reason it doesn't affect getDayClass