# How to share data between controllers in different modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have downloaded `Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker`, and I need to access to its controllers for their scopes. But I have absolutely no idea how to do it without editing the code in Datepicker, which I think isn't the way it should be done.

So I have my own app/module, `myApp` and I have a controller `MyController`, in which I need access to `UibDatepickerController` and `UibDaypickerController`, which are in `ui.bootstrap.datepicker` app/module. And I don't want to change the code in `ui.bootstrap.datepicker` module.

This is basically [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003910/how-to-pass-variable-to-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-custom-class) I posted while ago  but I have figured it out a lot I think. (Spent like 50 hours in this one :D)

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594140/how-to-share-data-between-two-modules-in-angularjs) doesn't work because you can't inject controller like you can inject a service.

Here is kind of my design:

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl() {
var vm = this;
vm.dt = new Date();
vm.options = {
  ...
};
vm.refresh = function() {
  //returns initialized value all the time (current date)
  console.log(vm.dt);
  $("#calendar").data("$uibDatepickerController").refreshView();
}
};
angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="CalendarCtrl as calCtrl">
  <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{calCtrl.dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em>
  </pre>
  <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div uib-datepicker="" id="calendar" ng-model="calCtrl.dt" datepicker-options="calCtrl.options"></div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="calCtrl.refresh()">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What, specifically, do you need access to? The date/day selected or something internal?

Comment: Selected date and also I need the ui.bootstrap.datepicker module to be able to have access to my variables in my controller.

Comment: For the date I'd just bind the value of the element to a variable in your controller, for direct controller to controller access Niles' answer is closer to what you'd want. Can you post a fiddle or something similar so we can better understand where you're trying to go?

Comment: I had kinda similar scenario where I had to include custom logic with date picker; for which I created a directive wrapped over bootstrap date picker and included my custom logic in directive

Comment: Could you please give some more information about that. I have studied directives for only a few hours now so I'm not sure how to do that. I had that same kind of idea myself that I could solve this with directives. Also now there is a brief code example in the question

Comment: I would like to point out that you really shouldn't be working with the DOM in your controller.  That is typically done in a Directive.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Would you care to elaborate? Okay after some googling now I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you make a service something like:

```
app.factory('thisfactory',function(){
  var data = null;
  var get = function(){
    return data;
  }
  var save = function(newData){
    data = newData;
  }
  return {get:get,save:save}
});
```

then you inject the factory into each controller and use it to pass data back and forth using the save and get methods

Comment: This would require me to edit code in ui.bootstrap.datepicker module, but it starts to seem as if there was no other option

Answer (score 0):

If you really need access in another module or controller to a value that is set in your View.  You can do what Niles has mentioned or you can setup a watch and then broadcast that so that other modules, controllers can access the value, but not the reference.

```
(function(){
    angular.controller("testController", testController);
    angular.controller("otherController", otherController);

    testController.$inject = ["$scope", "$rootScope"];
    otherController.$inject = ["$scope"];

    function testController($scope, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.$watch("vm.datePicker", function(newValue){
            $rootScope.$broadcast("DATEPICKER_CHANGED", newValue);
        });
    }

    function otherController($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        $scope.$on("DATEPICKER_CHANGED", function(event, obj) {
            console.log(obj);
        });
    }
})();
```